# Reference WinSCP.exe from PowerShell script executed from SSIS

Tags: powershell, ssis, gac, winscp, winscp-net

I am trying to execute a PowerShell script from within SSIS. My script starts with the `Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"` and it is erroring out because it cannot find the `WinSCP.exe` in the folder that houses my PowerShell script.  Come to find out the server admin did NOT install WinSCP into the GAC.  Is this creating my problem?
If so, how and where can I reference the `WinSCP.exe` in my script using `$session.ExecutablePath`?  Any help/direction would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Here is my script below:

```powershell
# Load WinSCP .NET assembly
Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"

# Declare variables 
$date = Get-Date
$dateStr = $date.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
#$fileDirectory = "\\abicfs2\apps\CoverageVerifier\"
#$filePath = "\\abicfs2\apps\CoverageVerifier\cvgver." + $dateStr + ".0101"
$filePath = "\\empqaapp1\coverageverifier_scripts\CoverageVerifier\cvgver.20190121.0101"

# Write-Output $filePath

# Set up session options
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
    HostName = "secureftp.iso.com"
    UserName = "account"
    Password = "password"
    SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 8C1lwAjxCNRF6B4kbPIeW52/GB+98FmLMt0AJNf/Sf4="
}

#$sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("FSProtocol", "2")

$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session 
# $session.SessionLogPath = "\\share\apps\CoverageVerifier\UploadLog.log" 


try
{
    # Connect
    $session.Open($sessionOptions)

    # Transfer files
    $session.PutFiles($filePath,"/").Check()
}
finally
{
    $session.Dispose()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to execute a Powershell script from within SSIS

It seems you believe you need to have WinSCP .NET assembly in GAC, so that you can execute it from a PowerShell script executed from SSIS. I do not think it's true. You need an assembly in GAC, only if you directly use it from an SSIS code. What is not your case.

You can simply store the `WinSCPnet.dll` and `WinSCP.exe` to your PowerShell script directory.

---

Anyway to answer your question:

> If so, how and where can I reference the WinSCP.exe in my script using $session.ExecutablePath?

```
$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session 
$session.ExecutablePath = "C:\path\WinSCP.exe"
```

(but as per above, I do not think you need it)

---

> Come to find out the server admin did NOT install WinSCP into the GAC.

You cannot install .exe file to GAC.

Comment: Thanks Martin.  I did need the assembly installed in the GAC because I will be executing my powershell script via SSIS.

Comment: Again, I do not think it is true, as I have written already in my answer. But I cannot try right now to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Excerpt from WinSCP assembly installation instruction (https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_install):

> The package includes the assembly itself (winscpnet.dll) and a
>   required dependency, WinSCP executable winscp.exe.
>
> The binaries interact with each other and must be kept in the same
>   folder for the assembly to work. In rare situations this is not
>   possible (e.g. when installing the assembly to GAC), make use of the
>   Session.ExecutablePath property to force the assembly to look for the
>   winscp.exe in a different location.